# Disable generate set and get for entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How DISABLED generate set and get for entity?

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppAdminBundle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the getter and setter for the entity is the main goal of the `doctrine:generate:entities` command (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters).

If you only need the entities, call the `doctrine:generate:entity` command (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class).